# Checking if a library is installed on the computer

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is there a way to check without raising (and rescuing) an error if a library/gem `"foo"` is installed on the computer and is available?

Probably, `ruby-gems` or `bundler` should have some relevant code in the source, but I cannot spot it.

Comment: `gem list foo`, or do you mean from within a program?

Comment: @matt Yes. From within Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spotted the relevant [source](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems.rb). I can do:

- Checking the entire load path:

  ```
   Gem.find_files("foo").any?
  ```
- Checking for only gems:

  ```
   Gem.find_files("foo", false).any?
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the [**pry**](http://rdoc.info/github/pry/pry/master/file/README.markdown),then you can do as below using the method [**`Pry::Rubygem.installed?`**](http://rdoc.info/github/pry/pry/master/Pry/Rubygem#installed%3F-class_method):

```
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$ irb
2.0.0p0 :001 > require 'pry'
 => true 
2.0.0p0 :002 > pry
[1] pry(main)> Pry::Rubygem.installed?('nokogiri')
=> true
[2] pry(main)> Pry::Rubygem.installed?('foo')
=> false
[3] pry(main)>
```

Or you can do as below:

```
require 'rubygems'

def installed?(name)
  if Gem::Specification.respond_to?(:find_all_by_name)
    Gem::Specification.find_all_by_name(name).any?
  else
    Gem.source_index.find_name(name).first
  end
end

installed?('nokogiri') # => true
installed?('foo') # => false
```